# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed.'

Tags: wpf, windows-10

I created a blank WPF Application

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser Name="WebBrowser1" ></WebBrowser>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I Click Run, this Exception appears

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Dispatcher processing has been
>   suspended, but messages are still being processed.'

If I remove the WebBrowser, then the App runs without Exception.
It was giving this Exception, then a few moments ago, I could run similar code, not it is giving me this unexpected Exception, then now it insists with this Exception.
How to solve it?

I think that this problem started after Visual Studio updated to Version 15.4.0 .

My Windows: Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.15063]

Stack Trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.IOleObject.SetClientSite(IOleClientSite pClientSite)
   at System.Windows.Interop.ActiveXHost.TransitionFromLoadedToRunning()
   at System.Windows.Interop.ActiveXHost.TransitionUpTo(ActiveXState state)
   at System.Windows.Interop.ActiveXHost.BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildWindow(HandleRef hwndParent)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildOrReparentWindow()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.OnSourceChanged(Object sender, SourceChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.SourceChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.PresentationSource.UpdateSourceOfElement(DependencyObject doTarget, DependencyObject doAncestor, DependencyObject doOldParent)
   at System.Windows.PresentationSource.OnVisualAncestorChanged(DependencyObject uie, AncestorChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnVisualAncestorChanged(Object sender, AncestorChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(DependencyObject e, AncestorChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(DependencyObject e, AncestorChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.AddVisualChild(Visual child)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_TemplateChild(UIElement value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.UseContentTemplate.BuildVisualTree(FrameworkElement container)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at WpfApp4.App.Main()
```

My Visual Studio 2017 Info:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017  Version 15.4.0
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.4.0+27004.2002 Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.7.02046
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual Basic 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA133 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2017
>
> Visual C# 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA133 Microsoft Visual C# 2017
>
> Visual F# 4.1   00369-60000-00001-AA133 Microsoft Visual F# 4.1
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.9.00809.2
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.0.30925.0 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017
>
> ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   1.0 Provides languages services
>   for ASP.NET Core Razor.
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.50921.0 For additional
>   information, visit https://www.asp.net/
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.0.30915.0 Azure App Service Tools
>   v3.0.0
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.10 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> JavaScript UWP Project System   2.0 JavaScript UWP Project System
>
> Merq   1.1.17-rc (cba4571) Command Bus, Event Stream and Async Manager
>   for Visual Studio extensions.
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2017 - v2.9.50719.1
>
> Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.3
>   Simplifying the configuration of continuous build integration and
>   continuous build delivery from within the Visual Studio IDE.
>
> Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
>   Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting
>   Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0 Microsoft Visual Studio VC
>   Package
>
> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   4.7.4-pre (c2d89eb) Support for
>   debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.
>
> NuGet Package Manager   4.4.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61707.200 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> TypeScript   2.3.5.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0 Interop layer for
>   hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.27004.2002 The
>   Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a
>   single universal app experience that can reach every device running
>   Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft
>   Windows 10 Software Development Kit.
>
> VisualStudio.IoT   1.0 Package with IoT components for Visual Studio
>
> VisualStudio.Mac   1.0 Mac Extension for Visual Studio
>
> WebJobs Tools v1.0.0   15.0.30923.0 WebJobs Tools v1.0.0
>
> Xamarin   4.7.10.22 (fe36bec) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   8.0.0.33 (HEAD/7a6a056e8) Xamarin.Android
>   Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.2.0.8 (9a9f054) Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

I reported this problem here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/131554/dispatcher-processing-has-been-suspended-but-messa.html

I filled a bug track here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3142780

Comment: Any code-behind or references to other DLLs? Have you try a new solution? If still, it must be something wrong with the Visual Studio, just reinstall it to have a try.

Comment: I just tried a new solution. I was having this issue on a old Project here, until I discovered it was related to WebBrowser, then I created a new Project, put the WebBrowser, hit Play, and the Exception appears from nowhere in my code. There is no my code behind. Just the control and the XAML.

Comment: Please post the stack trace, this can be interesting. Disable the 'just my code' setting and enable the .NET source debugging for a better stack trace.

Comment: I added the Stack Trace to this Question.

Comment: In the stack trace, there are a `Border`, an `AdornerDecorator`, and a template. Are you sure you're not using any additional styles, templates etc?

Comment: Yes, I Just created that WPF Project, put the WebBrowser, and 1% of the time, the Project runs, then it starts to give that exception. Now I opened the Project Run the Window with the Browser appeared. I stopped. Run again, then the Exception appears.

Comment: I reported this problem here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/131554/dispatcher-processing-has-been-suspended-but-messa.html

Comment: I filled a bug track here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3142780

Comment: I made a Time Travel Debug, and uploaded the files
WpfApp401.idx
WpfApp401.run
zipped :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5d9oJc6UeFKNGRReWJhWWx5UHM

Answer (score 4):

The problem went away after I uninstalled this Internet Banking Plugin:

[image: Uninstall WarSaw plugin]

Comment: You saved my day. Ou melhor... salvou meu dia, obrigado!

Comment: `Internet Banking Plugin`. Those are some pretty scary words...

Comment: How in the world does this have four upvotes. Anyone know what the actual issue was?

Answer (score 1):

Just navigate to url on start, solved to me.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    browser.Navigate("about:blank");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, appearing recently on a WPF app that's been around for years (more details in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76494211/wpf-dispatcher-processing-suspended-error-without-useful-stack-trace/76494212#76494212)).

In short, enabling `Prefer 32 bit` in the Release configuration fixed it for us. And made it faster too.

Absolutely no clue why yet!

[image]